# Advice on how to wire a 4 wire RGWY wifi thermostat to an old hvac with no c wire?

Tags: hvac, thermostat, furnace, thermostat-c-wire

I have a 4 wire RGWY coming out of the wall to my old thermostat with no additional wire available for c wire. I was going to use the green one instead as I saw a tutorial online, but when I got to the furnace control, it appears the yellow isn’t even hooked up, no c terminal. Could use some guidance. Thank you to anyone who has insight[image]
[image]

Comment: Jumper Rc-Rh.....

Comment: Did you even LOOK at the instructions taped next to the jumper block?

Comment: This is the old model, the Sensi app told me to leave this in place until the furnace wiring was changed. New model  is a Sensi touch screen.

Answer (score 1):

The top picture (with the timer) has noting to do with your HVAC.

It is a airflow (ventilation) controller for your home, not for heating or cooling.

On the new thermostat (model unknown) the instruction says to bridge the Rc-Rh using the Red wire.

Now you have 3 wires left.

They are interchangeable, means you can try to connect to any of the screws (G,Y,W). They should run, Heat or Cool or Fan only modes.

Just connect one and set the controller to cooling and find out if cooling is running, or is it heating or fan only.

Normally the Y=cooling, the W= heating, G=Fan only, but there is no normal in thermostats market.

Thermostat maker Emerson offers 3 options for "C" wire.

**1- Finding and using an unused wire as a c-wire**
If you do not have the "C" wire, go to option 2

**2- Using the g-wire as a c-wire**

If you can't find an unused wire or common wire, you can also use the fan wire or g-wire as a common wire. Disadvantage-- You can NOT run in Fan-only mode, but the Fan will run with cooling or heating.

**3- if you want to use all operation modes without restrictions**, you need a power source.

If there is not an extra unused wire running from the thermostat to the furnace, and using the g-wire as a common wire is not an option, in most cases, installing a Common Wire Maker Kit is the best solution.

Source: [source](https://sensi.emerson.com/en-us/support/c-wire)

Comment: Thank you for clarifying what that is!

I’m sorry the new thermostat isn’t shown it’s a Sensi touch screen model. 

https://www.amazon.com/gp/aw/d/B094X9LF35?psc=1&ref=ppx_pop_mob_b_asin_title

The Sensi instructions app said to leave the old one on there (pictured) until the hvac wires were changed - to do that first. I will look for other control panel, I could not find anything else except that air control panel as the instruction video showed there should be a panel to remove. More pictures to come if I find it. Thanks again

Comment: The Sensi Touch Smart Thermostat is a Wi-Fi enabled device. To install and configure your thermostat correctly, you must use the Sensi app. To start the installation process, download the Sensi app to your smart phone or tablet. It is a free download.